# Java code conventions. Mixing objects with methods?

Tags: java, user-interface, styles, conventions, convention

I don't want to waste anyone's time so straight to the point.

Which of the following examples is in line with style conventions?

Example 1

```
  // creating components

    JButton easyButton = new JButton("Easy");
    JButton hardButton = new JButton("Hard");

    // then containers

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    // then adding components to containers

    topPanel.add(easyButton);
    bottomPanel.add(hardButton);
```

Example 2

```
    // creating first container and all its components

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton easyButton = new JButton();
    topPanel.add(easyButton);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton hardButton = new JButton();
    bottomPanel.add(easyButton);
```

Comment: Well, you'd need to specify whose conventions for us to answer that. But I can't think of any conventions that would allow one of those but not the other.

Comment: This isn't covered by any convention I can think of. Go wild.

Comment: Readability is the main factor for consideration here.

Comment: Go with the second one.  Don't make my imagination jump repeatedly from one panel to the other as I read your code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Even if the reference object will be used at many points throughout the class ?

Comment: Sure.  As I read your code, I'm visualising what's getting drawn on the screen.  It makes more sense to describe in full what's going on in one part of the screen, then to move on to another part, and so on; than it does to hop around making all the panels, then hop around making all the fields, then hop around making all the buttons, and so on.  This isn't any kind of "code convention" though.  Just my personal taste.  Which is why I posted a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A factory method:

```
JPanel createButtonPanel(String buttonLabel) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(new JButton(buttonLabel));
    return panel;
}
```

Because both examples duplicate code, which is against any sane convention.

Comment: It is unlikely that all panels will have the same number and type of components in any scenario so I think the reuse here is quite contrived and therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Favoring readability, my personal style is to group related code together such as in your second example.

Here's what I believe to be a related example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them